# How to use ECDSA for multiple fields

Tags: java, ecdsa

Small question regarding elliptic curve digital signature algorithm, but for multiple fields.

By multiple fields, I mean:

This code here, which is ready to run, works like a charm and can perform ECDSA on **one** field, here as an example the field first name.

```java
private JSONObject sender() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, SignatureException {
    ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    KeyPair keypair = g.generateKeyPair();
    PublicKey publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();

    String firstName = "John";

    Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
    ecdsaSign.initSign(privateKey);
    ecdsaSign.update(firstName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
    String pub = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
    String sig = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("publicKey", pub);
    obj.put("signature", sig);
    obj.put("firstName", firstName);
    obj.put("algorithm", "SHA256withECDSA");
    System.out.println("----- the payload is:");
    System.out.println(obj);
    return obj;
}

private boolean receiver(JSONObject obj) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, SignatureException {
    Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance(obj.getString("algorithm"));

    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(obj.getString("publicKey")));

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    ecdsaVerify.initVerify(publicKey);
    ecdsaVerify.update(obj.getString("firstName").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return ecdsaVerify.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(obj.getString("signature")));
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        DigiSig digiSig = new DigiSig();
        JSONObject obj = digiSig.sender();
        boolean result = digiSig.receiver(obj);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException | UnsupportedEncodingException | SignatureException | InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DigiSig.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

However, I am having trouble knowing what to do when there are multiple fields. By multiple fields, here for example, I will use two, but imagine "a lot of fields".

```java
ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keypair = g.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();

String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
```

I have tried two ideas, but all quite inefficient I would say.

Attempt 1, repeat for every fields

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("publicKey", publicKey);
obj.put("signatureForFirstName", signatureForFirstName);
obj.put("signatureForLastName", signatureForLastName);
obj.put("firstName", firstName);
obj.put("lastname", lastName);
obj.put("algorithm", "SHA256withECDSA");
```

And the JSON sent to the receiver will look like this

```json
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "publicKey": "abc...",
    "signatureFirstName": "ghi...",
    "signatureLastName": "jkl...",
    "algorithm": "SHA256withECDSA"
}
```

Attempt 2, append **all messages into one**, sign it once, but ask the receiver to parse it

```java
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Doe";
String message = firstName + DELIMITER + lastName;

Signature ecdsaSign = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA");
ecdsaSign.initSign(privateKey);
ecdsaSign.update(firstName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
byte[] signature = ecdsaSign.sign();
String pub = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded());
String sig = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("publicKey", pub);
obj.put("signature", sig);
obj.put("message", message);
obj.put("algorithm", "SHA256withECDSA");
System.out.println("----- the payload is:");
System.out.println(obj);
```

Any combinations of delimiter, or even nested JSON:

```json
{
    "message": "JohnSOME_DELIMITERDoe",
    "publicKey": "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEMEV3EPREEDc0t4MPeuYgreLMHMVfD7iYJ2Cnkd0ucwf3GYVySvYTttMVMNMEKF554NYmdrOlqwo2s8J2tKt/oQ==",
    "signature": "MEUCIQCsuI4OcBAyA163kiWji2lb7xAtC8S0znf62EpdA+U4zQIgBcLbXtcuxXHcwQ2/DmiVfoiigKnefeYgpVXZzjIuYn8=",
    "algorithm": "SHA256withECDSA"
}

{
    "message": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    "publicKey": "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAEMEV3EPREEDc0t4MPeuYgreLMHMVfD7iYJ2Cnkd0ucwf3GYVySvYTttMVMNMEKF554NYmdrOlqwo2s8J2tKt/oQ==",
    "signature": "MEUCIQCsuI4OcBAyA163kiWji2lb7xAtC8S0znf62EpdA+U4zQIgBcLbXtcuxXHcwQ2/DmiVfoiigKnefeYgpVXZzjIuYn8=",
    "algorithm": "SHA256withECDSA"
}
```

Here, the receiver has to drill down layers or know in advanced delimiters.

The last two attempt are I believe quite inefficient. May I ask if there is a way to perform ECDSA on multiple fields?

Comment: What if, if sender and receiver treat it as a signing data instead of first name, last name?

Comment: In attempt 1, I think 1 keypair is enough? You would then have only 1public key value but n-times the signature value... Also, the real "need" is left a little foggy so if you would open up a little about what is the actual need behind the question, then maybe a whole different approach could be used

Comment: Correct @Jokkeri, one public key, thanks a lot! edited